# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' to 'Windows.Foundation.IAsyncAction'. An explicit conversion exists

Tags: c#, multithreading, azure, asynchronous, async-await

So I'm coding this software in C# and I get hit with this error message. For the life of me, I cannot figure it out and searching is not bringing up anything useful, no matter what I do.

The code itself:

```
private async Task LoginIoTHub()
{
    TypeJson command_json = new TypeJson();

    if (NowNetSta == false) return;
    if (IoTHubConnectFlag == false) return;

    if (TeamName == null)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Please don't let your team name be void when you call methods 'new IoTHubLocalService(xx,xx,xx)'");
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4));
    }
    else
    {
        if (LoginF == false)
        {
            try
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Start to login\r\n");

                LoginJson login_msg = new LoginJson();
                login_msg.DeviceID = BoardID;
                login_msg.name = TeamName;

                var messageString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(login_msg);

                command_json.Type = 1;
                command_json.Command = messageString;
                messageString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(command_json);

                var message = new Message(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(messageString));
                IAsyncAction Action = deviceClient.SendEventAsync(message);

                await Action;

                if (Action.Status == AsyncStatus.Completed)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Login success");
                    LoginF = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Login failed");
                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Login to IoT Hub failed, please check your team name and internet connection: " + ex.Message);
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What line is the error. is it `IAsyncAction Action = deviceClient.SendEventAsync(message);` Im guessing that is your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DeviceClient.SendEventAsync(Message)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.client.deviceclient#Microsoft_Azure_Devices_Client_DeviceClient_SendEventAsync_Microsoft_Azure_Devices_Client_Message_) returns a [Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Sends an event to device hub
>
> ```
> public Task SendEventAsync(Message message)
> ```

change code to

```
var Action = deviceClient.SendEventAsync(message);
await Action;
```

Also note that Task inherits from `IAsyncResult` and not `IAsyncAction` like in your example.

You can also check completion using [Task.IsCompleted Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.iscompleted(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
if (Action.IsCompleted) { ...
```

Comment: This partially works, but again the if statement breaks. Either "Action.Status" fails (read only) or the double "==" fails to work.

Comment: Yes, you did. My apologies. It's been a long day.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
IAsyncAction Action = deviceClient.SendEventAsync(message);
```

Async method calls return Tasks. Not IAsyncActions.

Assuming the return value of your function call `deviceClient.SendEventAsync(message)` is a `Task<IAsyncAction>` you should updated your code to this:

```
IAsyncAction Action = await deviceClient.SendEventAsync(message);
```

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx

Comment: I tried this, believe it or not. It throws another error though: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'Windows.Foundation.IASyncAction'.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line:

```
IAsyncAction Action = deviceClient.SendEventAsync(message);
```

SendEventAsync return a Task wether you expect a IAsyncAction. If an explicit conversion exists you can do the following:

```
IAsyncAction Action = deviceClient.SendEventAsync(message) as IAsyncResult;
```

But I think SendEventAsync returns `Task<IAsyncAction>` inside which means you have to await it:

```
IAsyncAction Action = await deviceClient.SendEventAsync(message);
```

Based on your comment:

> I tried this, believe it or not. It throws another error though:
>   "Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to
>   'Windows.Foundation.IASyncAction'.

I would guess that you just don't get a IAsyncAction. So you have to do it this way:

```
await deviceClient.SendEventAsync(message);
```

Comment: I just thought of this myself! It's working now, thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: @msammels your welcome. Accept the answer which fits your needs please or upvote if the answers were helpful to you.

Comment: Just came across another problem. If I go with the "await deviceClient" solution, the if statement below that breaks. Any further thoughts?

Comment: @msammels You should make a new question or Update this one, with actual code and error describtion